# Error to clone a project from Github with images to Netbeans

Tags: java, github, netbeans

Everytime I try to clone a project with images from GitHub to Netbeans, when I try to run show me errors like this:

https://hastebin.com/bexokemalo.bash

What I did?

[image: Netbeans clone]

[image: Netbeans open]

[image: NetBeans project]

This code have no errors, full code on github: https://github.com/dotrz/img

Comment: Please, post your code instead of using images

Comment: Please post [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

The line which has an NPE (NullPointerExecption) is in [`otrz/otrzJFrame.java#initComponents()`](https://github.com/dotrz/img/blob/f18ae1ef6e344e6998ea0bbd5b708ebfdb775669/src/otrz/otrzJFrame.java#L34)

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/imgs/test.png"))); // NOI18N
```

Try and decompose that line to check that:

- `jLabel1` is not null
- `getClass().getResource("/imgs/test.png")` is not null

Comment: I'm sorry, i don't understand, why this code runs on my work computer where i created this, but wont work when do clone in my home computer or my brother do clone...

Comment: Because the path of the resource might not be the same once cloned: again, split that long line into two separate declaration, in order to debug this.